# System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException with Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, release

I am using EF4 in windows form app. I got a problem whenever I run a release file in machine which doesn't have visual studio 2010 installed I always got this error :

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information

So far, the only workaround is install VS 2010 and rebuild solution in order to make the release run. It's so annoying, I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: Could you please provide a feedback to Leblanc Meneses ? If you're still unsuccessful, we can provide means to determine the missing components.

Comment: This most probably means you have a problem with .NET version. It doesn't have to be related to EF at all.

Comment: @Seb : I will test Leblanc Meneses's answer tomorrow, I'm now out of worktime.

Comment: I'm working on the exact same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101530/entity-framework-executestorequery-fails-on-deployed-systems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have the correct client profile installed on the client machine you might have dependencies to frameworks that are not in the base installation and need to be included as part of your deployment to the client.

You can quickly verify by selecting all the referenced dlls and setting Copy Local=True

And testing everything in the bin on a client machine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe on machine without VS is not installed framework 4.0? or in "target framework" on settings project set "full framework", but must set "client framework 4.0 or 3.5".

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: All client machines have Net Framework 4 installed. I used Net Framework 4 installer from VS 10 installer package.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, just remove the "buildProviders" block. It will probably work =)

Comment: You can always edit your answers instead of posting another one.

Comment: Also, you can format `<tags>` by surrounding them in [backticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)